# Vim completion + php namespace

Tags: php, vim, autocomplete, namespaces

How to configure vim completion namespaces for php. I use a plugin [indexer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3221) with omni completion.  Namespaces not supplements. Settings of indexer:

```
let g:indexer_disableCtagsWarning=1
let g:indexer_lookForProjectDir=0
let g:indexer_ctagsJustAppendTagsAtFileSave=1
let g:indexer_indexerListFilename=$VIMDIR."/indexer_files"
let g:indexer_tagsDirname=$VIMDIR."/tags"
let g:indexer_ctagsCommandLineOptions="-h '.php' -R --totals=yes --tag-relative=yes --PHP-kinds=+cf --regex-PHP='/abstract class ([^ ]*)/\1/c/' --regex-PHP='/interface ([^ ]*)/\1/c/' --regex-PHP='/(public |static |abstract |protected |private )+function ([^ (]*)/\2/f/' --exclude='*cache*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understood your question but [phpautocomplete.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171) might help you if it's php code auto-completion that you want.